# How to Enable PCEP session between PCC and PCE to get LSP state database?

Tags: python-2.7

reference link: http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-boron/user-guide/pcep-user-guide.html

I am trying to enable PCEP session between PCC and PCE to get LSP state using RESTCONF services, But I am getting error(response :404) if i introduce RESTCONF services in the python script. Here I am using the below link to get the response.

URL: /restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/pcep-topology/node/pcc:%2F%2F43.43.43.43

Can you please suggest me, If any change is required in the above URL.

Comment: I think the way how to use the above url using restconf is wrong. But i changed the ip address(43.43.43.43) as the ip address present in the mininet topology. Still i am getting the 404 error using restconf